# . unexpected kELSIF Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an ". unexpected kELSIF" error. I am really not sure what it is complaining about. I am running anested if else loop to check the values for either no company or no sub company. I have never seen this error before. It only throws the error on the second elsif statement. Here is my code:

```
      <tr>
        <% prime = w.positions.joins(:company, :hire_type).where(:hire_types => { :hire_type => "Prime" }).pluck('companies.company_name').uniq %>
        <% sub = w.positions.joins(:company, :hire_type).where(:hire_types => { :hire_type => "Sub" }).pluck('companies.company_name').uniq %>
        <% if ((prime.length == 0) && (sub.length == 0))%>
          <td class="tg-celltitle">Prime: </td>
          <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
          <td class="tg-celltitle">Subcontractor: </td>
          <td class="tg-datacell"></td>

        <% elsif ((prime.length == 0) && (sub.length != 0)) %>
          <td class="tg-celltitle">Prime: </td>
          <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
          <% sub.each do |s| %>
            <% if s == sub.first %>
              <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= sub.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
            <% end %>
            <td class="tg-datacell"><%= s %></td>



        <% elsif ((prime.length != 0) && (sub.length == 0))%>
          <% prime.each do |p| %>
            <% if p == prime.first %>
              <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Prime: </td>
            <% end %>
          <td class="tg-datacell"><%= p %></td>
          <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
          <td class="tg-datacell" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>"></td>


        <% elsif ((prime.length != 0) && (sub.length != 0))  %>
          <% prime.each do |p| %>
            <% if p == prime.first %>
              <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Prime: </td>
            <% end %>
            <td class="tg-datacell"><%= p %></td>
          <% sub.each do |s| %>
            <% if s == sub.first %>
              <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= sub.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
            <% end %>
            <td class="tg-datacell"><%= s %></td>

          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot closing parenthesis in the first `elsif`

```
<% elsif ((prime.length == 0) && (sub.length != 0)) %>
```

----------Update--------------------

You need to close the .each blocks with `<%end%>`

Full snippet after closing:

```
  <tr>
  <% prime = w.positions.joins(:company, :hire_type).where(:hire_types => { :hire_type => "Prime" }).pluck('companies.company_name').uniq %>
  <% sub = w.positions.joins(:company, :hire_type).where(:hire_types => { :hire_type => "Sub" }).pluck('companies.company_name').uniq %>
  <% if ((prime.length == 0) && (sub.length == 0))%>
    <td class="tg-celltitle">Prime: </td>
    <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
    <td class="tg-celltitle">Subcontractor: </td>
    <td class="tg-datacell"></td>

  <% elsif ((prime.length == 0) && (sub.length != 0)) %>
    <td class="tg-celltitle">Prime: </td>
    <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
    <% sub.each do |s| %>
      <% if s == sub.first %>
        <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= sub.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="tg-datacell"><%= s %></td>
    <%end%>
  <% elsif ((prime.length != 0) && (sub.length == 0))%>
    <% prime.each do |p| %>
      <% if p == prime.first %>
        <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Prime: </td>
      <% end %>
    <%end%>
    <td class="tg-datacell"><%= p %></td>
    <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
    <td class="tg-datacell" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>"></td>


  <% elsif ((prime.length != 0) && (sub.length != 0))  %>
    <% prime.each do |p| %>
      <% if p == prime.first %>
        <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= prime.length %>">Prime: </td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="tg-datacell"><%= p %></td>
    <% sub.each do |s| %>
      <% if s == sub.first %>
        <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= sub.length %>">Subcontractor: </td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="tg-datacell"><%= s %></td>
    <%end%>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I added the parenthesis after testing with no parenthesis, put the missing one in still have the issue. Seems to have the issue reguardless of if there are parenthesis there or even just around the values its checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% sub.each do |s| %>
```

You don't have an end statement for the block for this each statement.

Instead it's encountering the `elsif` so that's why the error.